# nth-child selecting extra elements

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="parent">
            <div>
                <div>A</div>
                <div>A</div>
                <div>A</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>A</div>
                <div>A</div>
                <div>A</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>A</div>
                <div>A</div>
                <div>A</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the following CSS:

```
#parent div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

I was expecting the fourth, fifth, and sixth "A"s to be blue since I was trying to target only the second child of the element with ID parent, however, the second and eighth were also made blue. Why is this and how do I fix it?

Here is an image of my result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEB4N.png

And here is an image of my expected result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVrCn.png

Answer (score 0):

Your css code is targeting all secound childs of `div's` inside of `#parent`.
You need to target only direct childs of `#parent` using the `>` selector:

```css
#parent > div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
        <div>A</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#parent > div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

You see the second and eighth div blue because they are also "the second" children of #parent (relative to their parent div). Using '>' in CSS selector applies your style only to straight children div of #parent.